# KeyError on handling csv file using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, keyerror

I am trying to read a CSV file from a folder and then assign it to a column for further use.The code am using is:

```
import pandas as pd

  
all_files = os.listdir("reward/") 
os.chdir(r"reward/") 

for file in all_files:  
    f_name = file
    df_1 = pd.read_csv(f_name)
    df_1=df_1.loc[:,[ ' Name', 'Total Reward', 'Performance']]
    print(df_1)
```

Throws an error saying:

```
KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index([' Name'], dtype='object'). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"
```

Comment: It seems like one of those columns is not in your dataframe. If I had to hazard a guess I'd say the column is probably `'Name'` and not `' Name'`.

Comment: Use `reindex`,  `df_1 = df_1.reindex(['Name', 'Total Reward', 'Performance'], axis=1)`

Comment: thank you so much, did the necessary corrections,it helped.